# How to understand intuitively or visually this high dimensional fact on volume of hyper-spheres?

Tags: geometry, analysis

Does anybody have a intuition or a way to visualize the fact that, as the dimension of a unity hyper-sphere (radius equals to 1) grows, its volume tends to zero?

I know how to do the calculations and prove that this is indeed true, but I'm wondering if there is an intuitively way to think about this fact.

Comment: consider a bounding hypercube of hypervolume 1. the higher the dimension, the more "corners" on the cube, and the hypersphere doesn't fill them.

Comment: You may be interested in [Mathoverflow question 128786](https://mathoverflow.net/q/128786) "History of the high-dimensional volume paradox". See also "Curse of Dimensionality".

Comment: By "unity hypersphere" do you mean radius $1$ or diameter $1$?

Comment: I meant  radius 1, thank you, I inserted in the post

Comment: Start with a segment length 1. Create the circle with the area 1. Fold it into a sphere volume 1. You could SEE how the PICTURE-VOLUME shrinks.